# sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply weights of evidence transformation to my data. I am trying to bin my data with the sc.woebin command, however, this: "sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found" error keeps on showing up. I have no clue as to what i could be doing wrong?

I have no clue as to why is it not working.I have tried different server, switching it up a bit, but i don't know what exactly is the problem and what exactly the error means in my case.

```
bins = sc.woebin(train, y = 'BAD',    
                 min_perc_fine_bin=0.02, 
                 min_perc_coarse_bin=0.05,  
                 stop_limit=0.1, 
                 max_num_bin=8,
                 method='tree')
```

*The expected result should be of it just processing the data. However, following is the actual result.
"""*

```
    """
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scorecardpy/woebin.py", line 702, in woebin2
    stop_limit=stop_limit, max_num_bin=max_num_bin, breaks=breaks, spl_val=spl_val)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scorecardpy/woebin.py", line 486, in woebin2_tree
    binning_tree = woebin2_tree_add_1brkp(dtm, initial_binning, min_perc_coarse_bin, bestbreaks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scorecardpy/woebin.py", line 446, in woebin2_tree_add_1brkp
    bin_add_1bst = binning_add_1bst(initial_binning, bestbreaks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scorecardpy/woebin.py", line 423, in binning_add_1bst
    .agg({'good':sum, 'bad':sum, 'bin':lambda x:'%,%'.join(x)}).reset_index()\
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1315, in aggregate
    return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 186, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 498, in _aggregate
    result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 449, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 432, in _agg_1dim
    return colg.aggregate(how, _level=(_level or 0) + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 773, in aggregate
    return self._python_agg_general(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 856, in _python_agg_general
    return self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 707, in _python_apply_general
    self.axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 190, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 844, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scorecardpy/woebin.py", line 423, in <lambda>
    .agg({'good':sum, 'bad':sum, 'bin':lambda x:'%,%'.join(x)}).reset_index()\
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-209-aa1b22b28748> in <module>()
      4                  stop_limit=0.1,
      5                  max_num_bin=10,
----> 6                  method='tree') 

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

EDIT: This is what my train looks like:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S3vR.png)

Comment: You need to give more details about code, can you post the hole script?

Comment: What does `train` look like?

Comment: I have added the image of the what the train looks like.

Comment: It's a python package with no tests and the code looks like it was developed by someone mid-seizure. It will be hard to tell if you're running into a bug or if your data is not clean. Is there something in `sklearn` that might work for what you want to do?